# JavaScript or Qt way to update a select box value?

Tags: php, javascript, c++, qt

So I have the following HTML and am trying to change which item is selected.

```
<select name="coolselectbox">
   <option value="default" selected="selected">---</option>
   <option value="something">Something</option>
   <option value="something-else">Something Else</option>
</select>
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
QWebElement defaultOpt = 
       this->page()->mainFrame()->findFirstElement("option[value=default]");

QWebelement somethingOpt = 
       this->page()->mainFrame()->findFirstElement("option[value=something]");

defaultOpt.removeAttribute("selected");
somethingOpt.setAttribute("selected", "selected");
```

And then also:

```
QWebElement selectBox = 
       this->page()->mainFrame()->findFirstElement("select[name=coolselectbox]");

selectBox.setAttribute("value", "something-else");
```

However neither of these seems to get the job done.

**Does anyone know a Qt solution, or is there perhaps some JavaScript snippet I can run to do this?**

Comment: php tag ? I don't know what you're smoking, but you should stop bfore posting on SO.

Comment: the stuff I got now is called Lamb's Breath.  It's alright.  And by alright I mean I am stoney baloney

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/). 
It will gave what are you looking for.